# Append to a value in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, here is my dilemma: I am trying to append *to a value* in JQuery. So, I have an `input` and what I want is to append to then end some text (in this case a dash). I tried `.append("-");` but that didn't work because it appended it to the back of the input and not the actual value of it. Then I tried getting creative with something like `append.val()` but I quickly realized you couldn't do that. In the code below, type in three characters into the name `input` and then it will start the mayhem. Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#editorTextInfoName").keyup(function() {
    var infoNameTextValue = $("#editorTextInfoName").val();
    $("#fullName").text(infoNameTextValue);
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    var infoNameTextValue = $("#editorTextInfoName").val();
    var editorTextInfoBoxLength = infoNameTextValue.length;
    if (editorTextInfoBoxLength == 3) {
      $("#fullName").append("-");
      $("#editorTextInfoName").after("-");
    }
  }, 1);
});
```

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
}
#image {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -45px;
}
.spacer {
  width: 15px;
}
hr {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
}
#fullName {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: orange;
  margin-top: -40px;
  }
#job {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  }
#jobLocationText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.otherText {
  color: seaGreen;
}
#emailAddress, #phoneNumber, #officePhoneNumber, #address, #website {
  font-size: 17px;
}
#extra1, #extra2, #extra3, #extra4, #extra5, #extra6 {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
#signatureEditorText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.editorTextInfo {
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.editorTextBox {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 2px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.editorTextBox:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
#dash1, #dash2, #dash3, #dash4 {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#dash1 {
  margin-left: -137px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#dash2 {
  margin-left: -104px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#dash3 {
  margin-left: -87px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#dash4 {
  margin-left: -54px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#editorTextInfoPhone1 {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
#editorTextInfoPhone2 {
  margin-left: -131px;
}
#editorTextInfoPhone3 {
  margin-left: -98px;
}
#editorTextInfoOfficePhone1 {
  margin-left: -50px;
}
#editorTextInfoOfficePhone2 {
  margin-left: -81px;
}
#editorTextInfoOfficePhone3 {
  margin-left: -48px;
}
.editorTextBoxPhone, .editorTextBoxOfficePhone {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 24px;
  border: 2px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.editorTextBoxPhoneOther, .editorTextBoxOfficePhoneOther {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 2px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.editorTextBoxPhone:focus, .editorTextBoxPhoneOther:focus, .editorTextBoxOfficePhone:focus, .editorTextBoxOfficePhoneOther:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="icon" href="Logo.ico">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>HTML Hub</title>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <center>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center>
                <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id="image" title="Picture to be displayed">
              </center>
            </td>
            <td class="spacer"></td>
            <td rowspan="4">
              <hr>
            </td>
            <td class="spacer"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center>
                <div id="fullName">Billy Staples</div>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center>
                <div id="job"><i>Programmer</i></div>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center>
                <div id="jobLocationText">at <b id="jobLocation">My Company</b></div>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="contactInfo" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="emailAddress"><span class="otherText">Email: </span><span id="emailAddressText">email@domain.com</span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="phoneNumber"><span class="otherText">Phone: </span><span id="phoneNumberFirst">111</span>-<span id="phoneNumberSecond">222</span>-<span id="phoneNumberThird">3333</span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="officePhoneNumber"><span class="otherText">Office Phone: </span><span id="officePhoneNumberFirst">444</span>-<span id="officePhoneNumberSecond">555</span>-<span id="officePhoneNumberThird">6666</span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="address"><span class="otherText">Address: </span><span id="addressText">1379 Philadelphia Avenue</span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="website"><span class="otherText">Website: </span><span id="websiteText">example.com</span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="extra1"><span class="otherText" id="extra1Label"></span><span id="extra1Text"> </span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="extra2"><span class="otherText" id="extra2Label"></span><span id="extra2Text"> </span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="extra3"><span class="otherText" id="extra3Label"></span><span id="extra3Text"> </span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="extra4"><span class="otherText" id="extra4Label"></span><span id="extra4Text"> </span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="extra5"><span class="otherText" id="extra5Label"></span><span id="extra5Text"> </span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
      &nbsp;
      <p></p>
      <table id = "editTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id = "signatureEditorText">Signature Editor</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class = "editorTextInfo">Name</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input id = "editorTextInfoName" type = "text" class = "editorTextBox">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, I actually meant `.after()` for the `input`, not `append()`. When I tried `.append()`, it didn't do anything.

My actual goal for this is so that it can be like a phone number `input` (I just was testing it out on the name `input`) so that you type in three numbers and then it adds a dash.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#editorTextInfoName").val($("#editorTextInfoName").val() + "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to this inside `keyup` function instead of `setinterval`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#editorTextInfoName").keyup(function() {
    var infoNameTextValue = $("#editorTextInfoName").val();
    $("#fullName").text(infoNameTextValue);
    
    var full_string = $("#editorTextInfoName").val().split("-").join(""); 
  if (full_string.length > 0) {
    full_string = full_string.match(new RegExp('.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");
  }
  $(this).val(full_string);
  });

});
```

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
}
#image {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -45px;
}
.spacer {
  width: 15px;
}
hr {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
}
#fullName {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: orange;
  margin-top: -40px;
  }
#job {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  }
#jobLocationText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.otherText {
  color: seaGreen;
}
#emailAddress, #phoneNumber, #officePhoneNumber, #address, #website {
  font-size: 17px;
}
#extra1, #extra2, #extra3, #extra4, #extra5, #extra6 {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
#signatureEditorText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.editorTextInfo {
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.editorTextBox {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 2px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.editorTextBox:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
#dash1, #dash2, #dash3, #dash4 {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#dash1 {
  margin-left: -137px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#dash2 {
  margin-left: -104px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#dash3 {
  margin-left: -87px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#dash4 {
  margin-left: -54px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#editorTextInfoPhone1 {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
#editorTextInfoPhone2 {
  margin-left: -131px;
}
#editorTextInfoPhone3 {
  margin-left: -98px;
}
#editorTextInfoOfficePhone1 {
  margin-left: -50px;
}
#editorTextInfoOfficePhone2 {
  margin-left: -81px;
}
#editorTextInfoOfficePhone3 {
  margin-left: -48px;
}
.editorTextBoxPhone, .editorTextBoxOfficePhone {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 24px;
  border: 2px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.editorTextBoxPhoneOther, .editorTextBoxOfficePhoneOther {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 2px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.editorTextBoxPhone:focus, .editorTextBoxPhoneOther:focus, .editorTextBoxOfficePhone:focus, .editorTextBoxOfficePhoneOther:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="icon" href="Logo.ico">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>HTML Hub</title>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <center>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center>
                <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id="image" title="Picture to be displayed">
              </center>
            </td>
            <td class="spacer"></td>
            <td rowspan="4">
              <hr>
            </td>
            <td class="spacer"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center>
                <div id="fullName">Billy Staples</div>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center>
                <div id="job"><i>Programmer</i></div>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center>
                <div id="jobLocationText">at <b id="jobLocation">My Company</b></div>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="contactInfo" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="emailAddress"><span class="otherText">Email: </span><span id="emailAddressText">email@domain.com</span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="phoneNumber"><span class="otherText">Phone: </span><span id="phoneNumberFirst">111</span>-<span id="phoneNumberSecond">222</span>-<span id="phoneNumberThird">3333</span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="officePhoneNumber"><span class="otherText">Office Phone: </span><span id="officePhoneNumberFirst">444</span>-<span id="officePhoneNumberSecond">555</span>-<span id="officePhoneNumberThird">6666</span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="address"><span class="otherText">Address: </span><span id="addressText">1379 Philadelphia Avenue</span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="website"><span class="otherText">Website: </span><span id="websiteText">example.com</span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="extra1"><span class="otherText" id="extra1Label"></span><span id="extra1Text"> </span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="extra2"><span class="otherText" id="extra2Label"></span><span id="extra2Text"> </span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="extra3"><span class="otherText" id="extra3Label"></span><span id="extra3Text"> </span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="extra4"><span class="otherText" id="extra4Label"></span><span id="extra4Text"> </span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="extra5"><span class="otherText" id="extra5Label"></span><span id="extra5Text"> </span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
      &nbsp;
      <p></p>
      <table id = "editTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id = "signatureEditorText">Signature Editor</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class = "editorTextInfo">Name</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input id = "editorTextInfoName" type = "text" class = "editorTextBox">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

May you try these?

```
 $(function() {
      $("#editorTextInfoName").keyup(function() {
        var infoNameTextValue = $("#editorTextInfoName").val();
        $("#fullName").text(infoNameTextValue);
        var infoNameTextValue = $("#editorTextInfoName").val();
        var editorTextInfoBoxLength = infoNameTextValue.length;
        if (editorTextInfoBoxLength == 3) {
          $("#fullName").append("-");
          $("#editorTextInfoName").after("-");
        }
      });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using polling to update '-' is not a good idea. You can check value on each **KeyUp** and decided to append '-'.

Here is [JSFiddle link for solution](https://jsfiddle.net/bjfqv9pv/3/).

```
$(function() {

  // Save editor and fullName in variable
  var $editorTextInfoname = $("#editorTextInfoName");
  var $fullName = $("#fullName");

  $editorTextInfoname.keyup(function() {

    // Get editor text
    var editorText = $editorTextInfoname.val();

    $fullName.text( editorText );

    if (editorText.length == 3){
      $editorTextInfoname.focus().val( editorText + '-' );
    }

    // Sync full name with editor text
    $fullName.text( $editorTextInfoname.val() );
  });

});
```